# HTTP 500.52 Error

Tags: asp.net

I am getting a "HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error" error message when I try to run my ASPX we application. I added code to redirect from http to https and it worked for a few months but now is broken.   Any ideas?

```
    <rewrite>
  <rules name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

[image]

Comment: Check the file: `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\schema\rewrite_schema.xml` Make sure it hasn't been altered with.

Comment: It has not been modified.